# Storing Android eclipse projects in version control?

Tags: android, eclipse, git

Ok, so I have an android project and a few related java projects in a directory (the workspace, essentially). I've added all of them to git. My .gitignore is as follows:

```
# OS Files
.DS_Store*
ehthumbs.db
Icon?
Thumbs.db

#Android
# built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# files for the dex VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# generated files
bin/
gen/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

#Java
*.class

# Eclipse
*.pydevproject
.metadata
bin/**
tmp/**
tmp/**/*
*.tmp
*.bak
*.swp
*~.nib

# External tool builders
.externalToolBuilders/

# Locally stored "Eclipse launch configurations"
*.launch

# CDT-specific
.cproject

# PDT-specific
.buildpath

# libgdx specific
*/libs/*
```

Now, when I try to check this out on another machine and import the eclipse projects into git there, I run into problems. The basic java projects work fine, but the android project complains about not being able to find the gen folder and if I try to do a clean, it complains that the project has no default.properties file. If I create the gen file myself, it still complains about the default.properties file, as well as complaining that it cant resolve java.lang.Object (!?). Not sure what's going on here. I'm guessing that something I should be checking in to source control isn't getting checked in, but I'm not really sure what. Any ideas?

Comment: maybe there is some extra dependency which is not available for the second IDE. i.e. Try to first check paths for all dependencies in the project configuration and compare it with the new environment.

Comment: It is ok to skip checking in the gen and bin folders, though it is normal for the build to complain about the missing gen folder on a fresh import - it normally clears up doing clean. It is required that default.properties is checked in (now project.properties in ADT 14), sounds like that is missing. If both machines are running different versions of the tool chain (14 and something older) that is a problem.

Comment: Ok, I think I fixed it. It looks like I had differing versions of the SDK/ADT and that was causing weird things to happen. Thanks cistearns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I was running into here was a result of having differing versions of the Android SDK/ADT as a result of doing this at just the wrong time. After I updated everything to be the same version, it all worked great.